# Add xaml child in different class

Tags: c#, class, methods

I want to add a new child to my StackPanel element (I named it ChatWindow). In the same class (MainWindow.xaml.cs) I can add a new child using this function:

```
        {
            TextBlock chatBoxItem = new TextBlock();
            chatBoxItem.Text = "TEST";
            ChatWindow.Children.Add(chatBoxItem);
        }
```

I also tried to make the method static, but both ways I can't change anything in XAML from a different class than the MainWindow.xaml.cs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: Create an instance of the MainWindow inside the class you are using, an simply call it:

```
class SampleClass(MainWindow _mw)
{
   MainWindow mw = _mw;
   TextBlock chatBoxItem = new TextBlock();
   chatBoxItem.Text = "TEST";
   mw.ChatWindow.Children.Add(chatBoxItem);
}
```

Better answer: Take advantage of MVVM and use a ViewModel which will help you change the items more dynamically.

Comment: I tried it like you said, but then I get the error at `TextBlock chatBoxItem = new TextBlock();` that it must be an STA-Thread. I added `[STAThread]` before the method, but nothing changes. I also tried to add it right before the TextBlock, but it says I can't add it there.

Comment: It is difficult to imagine what the problem is. Are you able to show us more code?

Comment: Sure. So I want to make a twitch bot, and in the WPF program I want to show chat messages. the bot is created like this: `Bot bot = new Bot();`, inside the bot class is a method, that's executed when someone sends a message in chat (I'm using the twitchLib library). And now I want to add a TextBox child to the StackPanel in the MainWindow from the Bot.cs class. When I call a method inside the mainwindow.xaml.cs, that created a TextBlock and adds it to the StackPanel it works perfectly fine, but I can't create a TextBlock inside another class or when I call the event from another class